# Get quote discount total for each applied discount/promo

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote

I want to display each  promo name and total applied for current quote in checkout/cart , right now i'm able to display the name of each promo like this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$discountTotal = 0;
$discounts = array();

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as ){
  if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '' || $item->getDiscountAmount() < 1) {
    continue;
  }
  $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
  foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId){
      $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
      $ruleName = $rule->getName();
      if (!empty($rule->getCouponCode())) {
        $ruleName = $ruleName . ' - <b>' . $rule->getCouponCode() .'</b>';
      }
      if (array_key_exists($ruleName,$discounts)) {
        $discounts[$ruleName] += $item->getDiscountAmount();
      } else $discounts[$ruleName] = $item->getDiscountAmount();
  }
}
return $discounts;
```

[image]

But the total amount for each promo is wrong, how can i get total for each promo applied in my quote